# Validating that a string contains only ASCII characters and digits

Tags: regex, bash

I'm doing this to validate a username:

```
if [[ "$username" =~ ^[a-z][_a-z0-9]{2,17}$ ]]; then
```

But actually, a username containing unicode characters like é, ç, à etc... is accepted.
What regex class should I use to limit strings to only ascii letters (a, b, c, d ... z) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[bullet-proof](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/bulletproof.html)** way is to simply spell out `[a-z]` as `[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]`. There! No messing with locales or funny character classes and supported on any shell since Jan 1 1970 00:00:00. Future-proof, no matter what your OS vendor, shell vendor, Unix standardization process or BOFH thinks is cool.

With an extra variable `lc` like

```
lc=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

the regex even becomes readable:

```
[$lc][_0-9$lc]{2,17}
```

This is what highly robust and portable `configure` scripts do.

Comment: Bulletproof right up until the point where you stop assuming everyone on the planet has an English name, and you _want_ to allow non-Latin characters. just joking, it answers the question but, in any case, `^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz][_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0-9]{2,17}$` is one butt-ugly regex :-)

Comment: What's ugly is that the semantics of `[a-z]` has a hidden dependency on the environment, which the OP hit with surprise. With `lc=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` the regex becomes a very readable `[$lc][_0-9$lc]{2,17}`.

Comment: Well, it's only _hidden_ if you don't have a lot of experience with internationalisation and localisation but I have that advantage working for a company that has to ship its products _many_ different cuntries. But your `$lc` trick makes your solution quite a bit more workable, so +1 for that. I'd suggest actually adding that to the answer rather than leaving it in a comment.

Comment: I'm going to go with this solution for now. It might be "ugly" but it's explicit and I'm sure I'll still understand how the script works years from now. You're right: what is ugly is the semantic of [a-z]. I'm probably going to mark your answer as accepted but I'm waiting for a few hours in case somebody finds a solution we didn't think of so far.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Explicit, self-documenting, future-proof: in one word: *elegant*!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this by first setting `LC_ALL=C` (possibly temporarily so as to not affect anything else). The more modern regex engines allow for locales which can fold accented characters onto their base character (or at least sequence them so they come between `a` and `z`).

Since the C locale only knows ASCII, this should fix the problem.

For example, see the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

username=amélie_314159

for locale in '' 'C' ; do
    export LC_ALL="${locale}"
    printf "LC_ALL set to %-3s: '%s' is " "'$LC_ALL'" "${username}"
    if [[ "${username}" =~ ^[a-z][_a-z0-9]{2,17}$ ]] ; then
        echo valid
    else
        echo invalid
    fi
done
```

which outputs:

```
LC_ALL set to '' : 'amélie_314159' is valid
LC_ALL set to 'C': 'amélie_314159' is invalid
```

Comment: I'd still like the strings to be regarded as unicode strings, especially in the rest of the script. And I'm not sure what the other effects of setting LC_ALL to 'C' could be.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional, that's why I stated you should localise the effect of the `LC_ALL` setting. In other words, set it only for the `if` statement, then revert it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
if [[ "$username" =~ ^[\x00-\x7f]{2,17}$ ]]; then
```

Comment: I'd really like to be able to do that (or more accurately `^[\x61-\x7a]$` since I'm only interested in a,b,c...,z. Unfortunately, it seems that bash regexes dont't understand the \x.. notation for characters. If you found a way to make it work, that would be awesome, though.

Answer (score 0):

Before you check with a regex if the username has the right length etc. you should sanitize the input string. That means instead of blacklisting what is not allowed you should whitelist what is actually allowed. In this case we would use e.g. `tr` before the actual regex to remove all unwanted characters beforehand. When the regex check follows it becomes much simpler.

```
echo "abc[日本語][ひらがな][カタカナ][äüéçà]abc" | tr -dc "a-zA-Z"
```

This would only leave `abcabc` as remainder.

Comment: This has likely all the problems of the original regex, namely, the dependence on the locale for what `a-z` means. And you are using it wrong, since `tr` doesn't take character classes like '[a-z]' but sets where only `-` is special. Your pipe doesn't filter out `[` and `]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the brackets, got that wrong (fixed). Unfortunately, your comment that this won't work is wrong see edit.

Comment: Well, it was wrong that it would whitelist only alphabetics, since it also whitelisted `[]`.